# JavaFX border correct width in Scene Builder but not on running program

Tags: java, css, border, fxml, styling

**The Problem:**
I have a HBox called MenuContainer within which I have a MenuBar, I have used FXML to lay things out and CSS to style. I want a 1px border beneath my MenuContainer so I gave it the style: "-fx-border-width: 0px 0px 1px 0px; -fx-border-color: black;" I know that the style sheet is properly set up as I have styled other elements within my project. 
My problem is that the border does not appear, with further experimentation I have found that the border starts to show when I increase the border width to 5px the border shows as what it should be (1px). I have spent hours trying to find a fix that isn't just setting the width to 5px as I don't know if this will work on different screen sizes and I am unhappy with such a lazy fix.
Interestingly enough when I view the layout in FXML's scene builder the border displays correctly however when I run the program it is not there, attatched are screenshots of this.[Executed Program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qM0VJ.png). [In Scene Builder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PD580.png)

**The Relevant Code:**
**FXML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import java.net.URL?>
<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.canvas.Canvas?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Accordion?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Menu?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.MenuBar?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.MenuItem?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.ScrollPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Separator?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TitledPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Tooltip?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.ColumnConstraints?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.HBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.RowConstraints?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>

<GridPane fx:id="mainGridPane" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.121" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="code.controllers.MainScreenController">


    <children>

        <!-- menu at the top of screen -->
        <HBox fx:id="menuContainer" GridPane.columnIndex="0" GridPane.columnSpan="2" GridPane.rowIndex="0" GridPane.hgrow="ALWAYS">
            <MenuBar fx:id="menuBar" HBox.hgrow="ALWAYS">
                <menus>
                    <Menu text="File">
                        <MenuItem text="New" />
                        <MenuItem text="Open" />
                        <MenuItem text="Save" />
                    </Menu>
                    <Menu text="Edit">

                    </Menu>
                </menus>
            </MenuBar>
        </HBox>

        <!--the toolbar-->
        <HBox fx:id="toolBar" alignment="CENTER_LEFT" GridPane.columnIndex="0" GridPane.columnSpan="2" GridPane.rowIndex="1">
            <Button fx:id="undoButton" styleClass="toolButton">
                <tooltip>
                    <Tooltip text="Undo" />
                </tooltip>
                <HBox.margin>
                    <Insets left="15.0" />
                </HBox.margin>
            </Button>
            <Button fx:id="redoButton" styleClass="toolButton">
                <tooltip>
                    <Tooltip text="Redo" />
                </tooltip>
                <HBox.margin>
                    <Insets right="15.0" />
                </HBox.margin>
            </Button>
            <Separator orientation="VERTICAL" />
            <Button fx:id="drawButton" styleClass="toolButton">
                <tooltip>
                    <Tooltip text="Draw" />
                </tooltip>
                <HBox.margin>
                    <Insets left="15.0" />
                </HBox.margin>
            </Button>
            <Button fx:id="cursorButton" styleClass="toolButton">
                <tooltip>
                    <Tooltip text="Move" />
                </tooltip>
            </Button>
        </HBox>


        <Canvas fx:id="mainCanvas" GridPane.columnIndex="0" GridPane.columnSpan="2" GridPane.rowIndex="2" GridPane.valignment="TOP" />

        <!-- pane at left hand side of screen -->
        <VBox fx:id="sidePane" GridPane.columnIndex="0" GridPane.rowIndex="2">

            <ScrollPane hbarPolicy="NEVER" styleClass="secondaryContainer">
                <Accordion fx:id="componentAccordion" style="-fx-background-color: #3c3f41">
                    <panes>
                        <TitledPane text="Inputs">
                            <Button styleClass="componentButton" />
                        </TitledPane>

                        <TitledPane text="Outputs">

                        </TitledPane>

                        <TitledPane text="Logic Gates">

                        </TitledPane>
                    </panes>
                </Accordion>
            </ScrollPane>

        </VBox>

    </children>

    <!--These properties dynamically size the components to the screen size-->
    <columnConstraints>
        <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" percentWidth="20.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
        <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" percentWidth="80.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
      <ColumnConstraints />
    </columnConstraints>
    <rowConstraints>
        <RowConstraints percentHeight="3.0" vgrow="NEVER" />
        <RowConstraints percentHeight="5.0" vgrow="NEVER" />
        <RowConstraints percentHeight="92.0" vgrow="NEVER" />
      <RowConstraints />
    </rowConstraints>

    <!-- points to the stylesheet that this markup file is using-->
    <stylesheets>
        <URL value="@../css/mainStyle.css" />
    </stylesheets>
</GridPane>
```

**CSS**

```
#menuContainer {
    -fx-background-color: #3c3f41;
    -fx-border-width: 0px 0px 1px 0px;
    -fx-border-color: black;
}
#menuBar {
    -fx-background-color: #3c3f41;
}

#toolBar {
    -fx-background-color: #3c3f41;
    -fx-border-width: 1px 0px 0px 0px;
    -fx-border-color: #585d5f;
}
```